# Add variables to url based on click events

Tags: php, html, css, url, variables

Let me start of with a brief overview of my goal: I am hoping to build a color based password. In more detail, there is a box that is 750x150px filled with two rows of 150x150 squares. Each of theses squares is randomly assigned one of 10 colors. The goal is for the user to click these colors in the same order that is preset.

I have the css and html built, and the php that determines each div's background color is complete. The issue that I have now is how to determine what divs (and therefore color) the user selects and in what order they are selected.

My aim is to have to color code added to the url, but i do not know how to do that. Could someone explain how to do that or another method to organize the user's choice in colors?

Also, another issue that occurs, how would i make sure that each color is displayed, but in a random div? As currently some will not show as others end up being in two divs.

currently my entire document is all in one page so that the variables for the div colors can be used for some if statements in the index

So if you have any suggestions or code for me, please help!

index.php:

```
 <?php "session_start" ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>colorlock</title>
 </head>



 <style media="screen" type="text/css">

 <?php


 $background_colors = array(
 "#FFFF00",
 "#FF3399",
 "#FF0000",
 "#990099",
 "#66FFFF",
 "#339900",
 "#000000",
 "#000033",
 "#FFFFCC",
 "#FF3399", 
 );

 $rand_background1 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background2 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background3 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background4 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background5 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background6 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background7 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background8 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background9 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
 $rand_background10 = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];


 ?>  

  #full {  
  height: 300px;
  width: 750px;

 } 



 #boxone1 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background1?>; 
 float: left;
 } 

 #boxone2 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background2?>; 
 float: left;
 } 
 #boxone3 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background3?>; 
 float: left;
 } 
 #boxone4 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background4?>; 
 float: left;
 } 
 #boxone5 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background5?>; 
 float: left;
 } 


 #boxtwo1 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background6?>; 
 float: left;
 } 

 #boxtwo2 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background7?>; 
 float: left;
 } 
 #boxtwo3 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background8?>; 
 float: left;
 } 
 #boxtwo4 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background9?>; 
 float: left;
 } 
 #boxtwo5 {  
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: <?=$rand_background10?>; 
 float: left;
 } 

 </style>






  <body>

  <div id="full">

  <div id="boxone1" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxone2" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxone3" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxone4" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxone5" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxtwo1" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxtwo2" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxtwo3" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxtwo4" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>

  <div id="boxtwo5" onclick="window.location='?name='+this.id" style=""></div>
  </div>
  </div>


  <?php

  if( $rand_background5 == $rand_background6)
{
  echo ("that was lucky!");
}
  else 
  {
  echo ("that was expected!");
  }

  ?>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you specifically need to track the clicks in the URL? If not, better would be to track progress silently in a JS array

```
var sequence = [];
$('#full > div').on('click', function() {
    sequence.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Then, after 3 clicks, there would be 3 entries in the `sequence` array - 3 IDs of DIVs.

As for ensuring each colour is output only once, the trick here is not only to pull out a random entry from the array, but to remove it from the array afterwards so it can't be picked again.

If you need to reference the colours array later on, you'll probably want to take a copy of it first, therefore.

```
$cols = array('#f00', '#00f', '#0f0', '#d70');
function getRandomColour() {
    global $cols;
    $num_cols = count($cols);
    $rand = array_rand($cols);
    $rand_col = $cols[$rand];
    echo $rand_col;
    unset($cols[$rand]);
}

echo getRandomColour();
```

Comment: not necessarily in the url. I just havent learned JS yet. So the syntax of your answer is gibberish to me. But ill look into it to see what i can do with it.

Comment: Well most of my answer was PHP. The 4 lines of JS simply set up an empty array, then, on each click, the clicked square is logged in that array. So at any point, to see what sequence they've clicked, that array knows. Try it - just `console.log` the array after a few clicks to see what it contains.

Comment: okay thanks. My only other issue is that the password needs to be dependant on the color in each div, who would (or could) I associate each random color with the div that it is in?

Comment: When i put the js in i get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: how do i fix that? sorry i havent used js before

Comment: Sorry - should have pointed out my answer used jQuery. Include jQuery or, if you want me to edit the answer to use only native JS, I can.